# Replacing my localhost with an IP

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

we finished a software that involves a teacher and student module, but the teacher module acts as the server in which the database is installed . want a situation where where when the student submit it will post to the teachers IP to be able to access the database, what PHP script can be used to fetch the database of the teachers system through her IP?

Comment: What if teachers got dynamic IP everytime?, Make it ID Specific not the the IP specific.

Comment: `her IP`?? give me her cell number

Comment: it wont work, i want it to automatically change when i type https://localhost i want it to change to https:// "preferred IP" autoly

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can see this working and be secure is:

- Teachers would need to set up some type of DDNS
- A server with a static IP address will need a database of the teachers and they're DDNS host names.
- Students would post to the static server.
- Static server would then relay the $_POST data to the appropriate DDNS hostname.

The reason this is not feasible is that along with DDNS setup you will also need to configure each teacher's routers/firewalls to redirect port 80 to the teachers computers.

You are better off having the teachers pull the data.

Comment: but remember this is done locally,do How does DDNS come in, it is a local networking routing that am doing not cloud.

Comment: Are you meaning they are all in the same room (classroom presumably) and the teachers and students are on the same network?

Comment: yes!but the student apps are drawing data from the teachers database, actually, instead when this is typed on the student computer https://localhost, i want it to change to this https://"teachers IP" automatically

Comment: OK teachers and students on the same network,... Seems,... Wrong, but OK,... Should be able to use the teacher's system name which should be resolvable by DNS on the network.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is rather vague, doesn't connect? doesn't resolve? generates an error? If it's one of the first two you likely have some type of networking issue, such as a firewall on the teacher's system.

Comment: its more or less like when local hosts inputed, it automatically changes to another iP adress